# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d missing?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

Is xorg.conf.d no longer used by Arch Linux?  If so, does anyone know where the configuration files that once lived under said directory now reside?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default X config files live in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d in arch. You can still put them in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d if you want.

Comment: This is the same under Debian Stretch.

Comment: Same also for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus.

Comment: It's not "if you want", the file in `share` can be overwritten by the system, while the `/etc` one will stay. Copy a version of `share` to `etc` if you want to modify it.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that Arch Linux no longer places the default config files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, it now leaves that wholly to system-specific (user-made) config files.

> Note: Arch *supplies default configuration files* in **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d**, and no extra configuration is necessary for most setups.

> Xorg uses a configuration file called xorg.conf and files ending in the suffix .conf for its initial setup: the complete list of the folders where these files are searched can be found at [1] or by running man xorg.conf, together with a detailed explanation of all the available options.
>   Using .conf files
>   The /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directory stores host-specific configuration. You are free to add configuration files there, but they must have a .conf suffix: the files are read in ASCII order, and by convention their names start with XX- (two digits and a hyphen, so that for example 10 is read before 20). These files are parsed by the X server upon startup and are treated like part of the traditional xorg.conf configuration file. The X server essentially treats the collection of configuration files as one big file with entries from xorg.conf at the end.
>   Using xorg.conf
>   Xorg can also be configured via /etc/X11/xorg.conf or /etc/xorg.conf. You can also generate a skeleton for xorg.conf with: